# Error Index out of range converting pdf to image for processing it

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

Trouble with converting result to subscriptable?
Error converting PDF to images: 'Result' object is not subscriptable.
I also tried different libraries like PDF2IMG and it was getting stuck on processing What do you suggest best edit for this I am trying to convert pdf to image then process it and get query answers type chatting based.
Error:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\arbaz\Documents\MultiLangModel\venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\arbaz\Documents\MultiLangModel\app2.py", line 54, in <module>
    response2 = get_gemini_response_from_pdf(input_prompt2, pdf_images, input2)^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\arbaz\Documents\MultiLangModel\app2.py", line 14, in get_gemini_response_from_pdf
    response2 = model2.generate_content([input_prompt, pdf_images[0], input2])~~~~~~~~~~
```

Code:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
import google.generativeai as genai
import convertapi
import os
import io
import tempfile

convertapi.api_secret = 'Secret Key'
genai.configure(api_key='Secret Key')
def get_gemini_response_from_pdf(input_prompt, pdf_images, input2):
    model2 = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro-version')
    response2 = model2.generate_content([input_prompt, pdf_images[0], input2])
    return response2.text

def convert_pdf_to_images(uploaded_file):
    try:
        temp_file = f"tmp{uploaded_file.name}"
        with open(temp_file, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(uploaded_file.read())

        result = convertapi.convert('jpg', {'File': temp_file}, from_format='pdf')
        if result['response']['status'] == 'Ok':
            return result['files']
        else:
            st.write(f"Conversion failed: {result['response']['message']}")
            return []
    except Exception as e:
        st.write(f"Error converting PDF to images: {e}")
        return []

st.set_page_config(page_title="Document Reader using AI")
st.header("This is my document reader using AI")

input_prompt2 = """
               You are an expert in understanding documents such as passport, bank statements, and financial investments into assets.
               You will receive input pdf of passport, bank statements, invoices, and financial investments into assets &
               you will have to answer questions based on the input image
               """
input2 = st.text_input("Input Prompt for PDF Document: ", key="input2")
uploaded_file2 = st.file_uploader("Upload a PDF file", type="pdf")
pdf_images = []

if uploaded_file2 is not None:
    pdf_images = convert_pdf_to_images(uploaded_file2)
    for img_data in pdf_images:
        img_bytes = img_data['data']
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes))
        st.image(image, caption="Converted Image", use_column_width=True)
    
    submit_pdf = st.button("Generate Pdf Response")
    if submit_pdf:
        response2 = get_gemini_response_from_pdf(input_prompt2, pdf_images, input2)
        st.subheader("The Response is")
        st.write(response2)
```

I am trying to convert pdf to image then process it and get query answers type chatting based.
Tried multiple libraries like pdf2img and other logic